# Image warping of two images using python

Tags: image, transformation

I want to co-register two images i.e. master and slave image. For this I need to warp the image. I am implementing it in python. Can any body help me in this?

Comment: Please update you question with sample code; ( What ever you have tried ) And explain the problem that you are facing. It will make easier to answer the question.

Comment: I want to co-register two images. I have applied rotation and translation matrix to slave image to co-register it with master image. But this is a hit and trial method. I want to optimize it using image warping @KeshanDeSilva